# Can not install everpad on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, evernote, everpad

I wanted to install everpad on ubuntu 13.10 
when I entered the ppa it says that 13.10 is supported 
[everpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nvbn-rm/+archive/ppa)

When I tried to install it this is what I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package everpad
```

any ideas how to fix this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (20 oct), the ppa does not contain an everpad package for saucy. You could try to wait until it is made available.

This is NOT RECOMMENDED, but if you really cannot wait, you could try to install it by modifying the software sources entry, specifying raring as your distribution. It *might* work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your repositories first so that you can use new ppa's. Do:

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

and try again.

Comment: No go, that did not work

Answer (score 1):

This message means, that there are no packages for 13.10 in the repository you're looking for. Try to change chanel from `stable` to `unstable`, if you need everpad right now.
Just wait for a few days until needed package appears in repository.